# How to fit content in a row and prevent overflow in react-native?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a tableview row like the below.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
  <Text>{user.fullName}</Text>
  <Button/>
</View>
```

Above renders so that name sticks to the left and button sticks to the right.

```
-----------------------------------
 User's Full Name           Button
-----------------------------------
```

It's all good when user's full name is short enough.

However, when user's name is long.
This is how it looks.

```
-----------------------------------
 User's Very Very Long Full Name         Button
-----------------------------------
```

Now, the row content overflows the row's width and button goes out of the screen and becomes invisible.

What I want is this.

```
-----------------------------------
 User's Very Very Long...   Button
-----------------------------------
```

How do I achieve this with flexbox model?

How do I make the `name` to grow and fill the available width, but not exceed?

Note that `Button` can grow or shrink based on the local state.

Also, is there equivalent of `text-overflow: ellipsis` on react-native?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set `flex:1` on the Text to grow relative to the remaining flex items(Button here). There is no flex set on Button, it will occupy as much space it needs. See [numberOfLines](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#numberoflines) docs. You can set it to 1 to make the text ellipsize

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
  <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{flex:1}}>{user.fullName}</Text>
  <Button/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar issue and fixed it by adding this to the view containing the text. Then the ellipsis showed up and the text no longer overflows.

```
flexShrink: 1
```

[Source](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/flexdirection-row-breaks-wrap-and-forces-content-off-screen)

Comment: For my use I had to have `numberOfLines={1}` on the Text element, and `{flexGrow:1, flexShrink: 1}` on the containing View ‍♂️